# How to suppress "Browser is attempting to close the tab" alert in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am developing a simple website with flash card questions and answers. When a question card is clicked, a window opens up and displays the question and the same for the answer.

There is a close on click when the user wishes to move on. When this is clicked an annoying message from IE pops up alerting that the browser is attempting to close the tab. I wish to suppress this message.

Can someone suggest on how this can be done?

An example of the functionality that I'm expecting can be seen here:

https://www.basenji.org/BasenjiU/Owner/Handbook/101GuideFC.html

Comment: Clear question, let's see if anyone can answer it.

Comment: I believe that you can't bypass it, on purpose. I would personally seek another way, like using an `<iframe>`.

Comment: @zneak But I see that in the link that I have posted, the alert doesn't show up. And where to use iframe? for the question?

Comment: I did not test it, but you can try this: http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/01/how-to-close-browser-window-without.html basicly, call `window.open('', '_self', ''); ` before closing.

Comment: I wrote it before looking up your edit. I'm clearly not right, then. How exactly do you open the window?

Comment: I'm opening a new window with a simple window.open(url, name, windowProperties). windowProerties are a few properties like scrollable, resizable and others

Comment: Please show your code (preferably, a minimal case that actually reproduces the issue). The confirmation prompt appears when a window has been created with HTML, not when it has been created with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Kennypu.! Your answer helped.

I just had to put a `window.open('','_self','');` just before closing the window.

Thanks to all for responding.!